# numbered sublist

Tags: numbering, enumerate

Here is what I want to do -

```
1. List 1
 1. sub list 1
 2. sub list 2
```

I tried doing this,

```
\begin{enumerate}    
  \item List 1

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

But this gives me -

```
1. List 1
 a. sub list 1
 b. sub list 2
```

How should I go about this.

Comment: The subnumbering you propose is rather ambiguous. Using letters instead of numbers prevents this ambiguity.

Comment: @egreg I agree. But I have to follow an existing pattern here. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do that using the [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem):

[image]

### Notes:

- As egreg commented there is a reason why the defaults are the way they are as this can be ambiguous and if the list is rather long, then it may not be obvious at what list depth you are at.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}    
  \item List 1

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```